# react-native-iap Issue with setting IOS In App Purchase

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this code and it's working on Android. but For IOS it is not.
I created a new In app purchase Item with product Id in app store connect, and it saved under drafts. I used the same id in getProducts but it didn't work. What I am doing wrong ??

Also I'm getting an error in my catch `sku is required for IOS purchase`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  initConnection,
  purchaseErrorListener,
  purchaseUpdatedListener,
  flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid,
  finishTransaction,
  requestPurchase,
  getProducts,
} from 'react-native-iap';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { useSaveInAppPurchaseMutation } from '../store/queries/paymentAPI';

const useReactNativeIAP = ({ productId, postId, handleFinish }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  let purchaseUpdateSubscription = useRef(null);
  let purchaseErrorSubscription = useRef(null);
  const [savePurchase] = useSaveInAppPurchaseMutation();

  //Get the current OS
  const appType = Platform.OS;

  const getProductsList = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getProducts({
        skus: ['boost_ad_for_a_month'],
      });
      console.log('RES:: ', res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }, [productId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const connection = await initConnection();
      if (connection) {
        await getProductsList();
      }

      try {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          await flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn('flush error', error.code, error.message);
      }

      purchaseUpdateSubscription.current = purchaseUpdatedListener(
        async (purchase) => {
          const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
          if (receipt) {
            const savePurchaseResponse = await savePurchase({
              receipt,
              productId,
              postId,
              appType,
            });
            finishTransaction({ purchase, isConsumable: true });
            if (savePurchaseResponse?.order?.items?.[0]?.postId) {
              handleFinish();
            }
          }
        }
      );

      purchaseErrorSubscription.current = purchaseErrorListener((error) => {
        console.warn('purchaseErrorListener', error);
      });
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      if (purchaseUpdateSubscription?.current) {
        purchaseUpdateSubscription.current?.remove();
        purchaseUpdateSubscription.current = null;
      }

      if (purchaseErrorSubscription) {
        purchaseErrorSubscription?.current?.remove();
        purchaseErrorSubscription.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [
    appType,
    getProductsList,
    handleFinish,
    navigation,
    postId,
    productId,
    savePurchase,
  ]);

  const purchase = async () => {
    try {
      await getProductsList();
      await requestPurchase({
        skus: [productId],
        andDangerouslyFinishTransactionAutomaticallyIOS: false,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  return {
    purchase,
    getProductsList,
  };
};

export default useReactNativeIAP;
```

Could the issue be is that my In-App Purchase is in Draft section in app store connect, if yes what should I do to change that ?